# Answer section in Profile shows false Results

Tags: bug, activity-tab

The number of votes are correct, but the coloring is wrong

First and second answer, mine are **not** the accepted answers

[image]

As far as I can tell, only Stack Overflow shows that behavior, DBA and the meta sites look "normal"

Comment: This has been reported on über-meta already

Comment: Likely a cross-site duplicate of [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749/478746)

Comment: @Zoe what is über-meta? i don't have an account on Stackechange meta, besides this only doesn't work on SO and not globally

Comment: Sure is wrong on other sites too. You think I've got [two accepted answers on the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson)?

Comment: i have two account and i checked only those, DBA doesn't seem to suffer the same problem. Nobodfy is forced to read meta stackExchange or to be member,

Comment: Well let's stick to DBA then. How about this example https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/171/jcolebrand?tab=topactivity and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/in-sql-is-it-composite-or-compound-keys/3136#3136

Comment: This is a known network-wide issue after the renewal of the Activity page. Some properties on the answers are referring to their question instead, like the accepted status, icons on "followed post"...